# LWC Function calls

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, web, component

I am creating a simple component that retrieves multiple URL and Description fields in a record (e.g. url1__c, desc1__c, url2__c etc) and transforming it into an Array of object in a JavaScript variable so that I can display it as an clickable Avatar with description.

I am already able to query the record via calling an apex (because the object is not supported by the UI Reference API) using the @wire call. In the wire adapter function, I want to process the data so that I can compute the icon. I'm unable to call any function inside though. Any advise? Sample code as follows:

**NOTE**: I know I can do the same transformation in Apex but want to do it in JavaScript for specific design purposes.

```
@wire(getContent, { recordId: '$recordId' })
wiredContent({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else if (data) {
        this.contents = new Array()
        for(var x=0;x<data.length;x++){
            if(data[x].URL1__c!=null){
                iconType = getIconType(data[x].URL1__C);
                this.contents.push({
                    key : 'URL1__c',
                    iconType : iconType,
                    docURL : data[x].URL1__C,
                    docDesc : data[x].Desc1__c
                });
            }
            // additional if-condition here
    }
}

getIconType(docUrl){
    var ext = docUrl.substr(docUrl.length,3);
    if(ext.toLowerCase()==="pdf"){
        return "doctype:pdf";
    }
    // additional if-condition here
}
```

Comment: Woops. I figure it out. I can call the function by adding the "this." keyword when calling it from the wiredContent().

Comment: might as well add it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted in your own answer, your code is missing `this` on the function call. It’s required because `getIconType` is a class method. You can learn more about JavaScript classes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

As for your code sample, it can be greatly simplified by using modern JavaScript array functions.

```
@wire(getContent, { recordId: '$recordId' })
wiredContent({ error, data }) {
   if (error) {
       console.log(error);
   } else if (data) {
       this.contents = data
           .filter(d => d.URL1__c != null)
           .map(d => {
               return {
                   key: 'URL1__c',
                   iconType: this.getIconType(d.URL1__c),
                   docURL: d.URL1__c,
                   docDesc: d.Desc1__c
               };
           });
   }
}

getIconType(docUrl){
   if (docUrl.endsWith('pdf')) { 
       return "doctype:pdf";
   }
   // additional if-condition here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Woops. I figure it out. I can call the function by adding the "this." keyword when calling it from the wiredContent().